# Page numbering and title issues

Tags: sharelatex

I have got some problems with page numbering and titles. I inserted command 
    `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\listoffigures` command
My intension was to start arabic pagenumbers from the introduction page . But here I have some blank spaces after the list of figures page . So page number started from that page . How can i resolve this ?

Also another issue is with title. The title of the article is seen from the contents page itself. I prefer to see it in footer only from the introduction page. How can i attain this .

My main.tex page is shown below

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}}
\usepackage[rawfloats=true]{floatrow} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{The title}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{the title}
\author{mark hedgen}
\date{May 2015}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}
\chapter{Research Methodology}
\input{chapters/ResearchMethodology}
\chapter{Literature Review and Theoretical considerations}
\input{chapters/RelatedWorks}
\chapter{General Background}
\input{chapters/Background}
\chapter{Pre Study}
\input{chapters/Casestudy}
\chapter{Requirements Specification}
\input{chapters/RequirementSpecification}
\chapter{Implementation}
\input{chapters/Implementation}
\chapter{Evaluation}
\input{chapters/Evaluation}
\chapter{Discussion}
\input{chapters/GeneralDiscussion}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/Conclusion}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendices}
\input{chapters/appendix}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a lot of `\input` from files we have no access to. It is quite difficult to reproduce your issue here

Comment: @botguide `\chapter` make blank page. You could write, for example, `\chapter{Introduction}` into `chapters/Introduction` file. Moreover, you could use `\include` instead `\input`.

Comment: it's usually safe to add `\clearpage` before `\chapter`, `\pagenumbering` takes effect with the current (in process) page, so you need to get to a new page before making the change.

Comment: \clearpage works with my issue of page numbering. And now I have only the issue of title starting on contents page.